# How to performance test code in a browser

Tags: javascript, performance-testing

I've got a web application that performs some AJAX calls and then processes the result. Depending upon what is sent to the browser this processing could be quite heavy.

I'd now like to generate performance statistics on the finished code. I'm thinking about using Selemium to automate my tests. This will allow me to automatically click the buttons to start the testing, but I don't see how to detect when the code has completed.

I had been thinking about using either the pageloaded event or (given that I'm using JQuery) getting Selenium to test to see that all AJAX calls have been completed. However these events can (and do) trigger the JavaScript I'm trying to monitor!

Does anybody know of a mechanism to detect when all JavaScript has been completed?

Thanks

Comment: did you check Selenium?

Comment: IE11 has "UI Responsiveness and Memory Profiling tools that help developers diagnose and fix performance issues" so that could be something you want to look at, but that probably doesn't do everything you want.

Comment: @Carlos Barcelona. I did look at selenium but the best I could come up with was calling a JQuery script to "return $.active". This will tell me when the last AJAX call as terminated, but not when JavaScript triggered by the call has completed. Did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: @Jake Morrison. That looks interesting - It might give me an idea about what's going on inside the browser, but I'll need away to automate it. Thanks

Comment: @Stormcloud Selenium is very powerful, I believe we could do it. Could you post some simplified code, to see what are you doing exactly?

Comment: Hi @Carlos Barcelona, At this stage I'm just looking for an approach, but can add any code that may be required. Is there a specific API you could point my at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform just some statistics you could use [Speed Tracer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/).  "`Speed Tracer is a tool to help you identify and fix performance problems in your web applications.`"

But if you want to do some more concrete tests (stress, performance, etc.), I would propose you to use Selenium. There you could use [waitForElementPresent](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#the-waitfor-commands-in-ajax-applications) to wait for the needed elements, produced by your Ajax calls, in a dynamic period.

```
waitForElementPresent(locator)
```

If your elements were already loaded, and you just fill in the data, you could always force to do add a new element at the end of the body.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {data: somedata },
  url: someurl,
  success: function(html){
    $("<div/>", {
      id: 'finnishedId',
    }).appendTo("body");
  } 
});
```

Comment: I see - rather then trying to directly access information about how busy the JavaScript interpreter is we can using the existence of the "finnishedId" tag as a proxy to indicate that processing has been completed. I think that should give me what I need. Thanks.